# Mock method to not throw exception

Tags: java, jdbc, powermockito

When using `DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);` that throw "SQLException no suit driver for CONNECTION_STRING" if CONNECTION_STRING is incorrect.

How to mock this method to not throw exception and just return a value? I tried the code below but it's not work:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(DriverManager.class);
PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mock(Connection.class));
```

Comment: Consider using a `javax.sql.DataSource` instead of `DriverManager`, and then mock the data source.

Comment: Can you refactor so that that line of code would be encapsulated in its own class (e.g. `ConnectionProvider`), instance of which you would then inject into the code-under-test? This would then allow you to simply mock a connection provider for your tests, instead of using power tools for preventing the real connection access code from running.